# Triggering password save dialog in browsers?

Tags: html, forms, authentication, passwords

I already tried solutions in these 2 questions:
[Why isnt the browser asking to remember the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580379/why-isnt-the-browser-asking-to-remember-the-password?rq=1) and
[How does browser know when to prompt user to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763/how-does-browser-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password), but I can't get the browser to record the password of the login form on this site: http://lksonorizacao.com.br/newsite/?painel. The form is placed there by PHP, no AJAX or anything dynamic. This is the form's code:

```
<form action="./?painel" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" autofocus autocomplete /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" />
    <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
</form>
```

I have no idea of what to do.

Comment: thats browser facility, if I mark in mozilla "do not offer more passwords save"...your code will die achieving a save prompt.

Comment: Turns out a plugin disabled saving passwords on my browser...